# Modifying fixed expressions such as 「駄々をこねる」 adjectivally and adverbially

Tags: expressions, na-adjectives

I came across the following sentence:

> 子供みたい**な**駄々をこねる

It felt a bit weird (possibly because I'm not very familiar with either 「駄々」 or 「こねる」 and think of the expression as a big verb) and made me wonder whether 「みたい**に**」 would also work. Google results showed that both 「子供みたい**な**駄々をこねる」 and 「子供みたい**に**駄々をこねる」 are used.

I feel that you can replace 「な」 with 「に」 in the above sentence without changing the meaning very much, but if you compare it to something like 「嘘をつく」, the meaning changes for some reason.

> 子供みたい**な**嘘をつく: the lies are childlike
>   子供みたい**に**嘘をつく: the way of lying is childlike, but the lies aren't necessarily

Why does this happen or is my intuition even correct? Either way, what is the difference between using 「な」 and 「に」 in 「子供みたい◯駄々をこねる」 apart from modifying the noun or the verb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (A) 子供みたい**な**嘘をつく
> (B) 子供みたい**に**嘘をつく

(A)と(B)とは全く違います。
*(A) and (B) are two quite different sentences*.

(A)については、嘘には２種類ある。子供のつく無邪気な嘘。もう一つは大人のつく陰険な嘘。(A)の文章は、彼/彼女は大人なのに子供のような（無邪気な）嘘をつくという意味です。
*As for (A), it tells that there are two kinds of lies. An innocent lie told by children. And an insidious/crafty lie told by adults*.
*(A) implies that the person tells an innocent lie just like being told by a child though he/she is an adult*.

(B)については、実際はどうか知りませんが、子供は嘘をつく。しかし、大人は嘘をつかないということを前提にしています。(B)の文章は、彼/彼女は嘘をつかないと思われている大人なのに子供のように嘘をつくという意味です。
*As for  (B), it is based on, apart from the true fact, that children are supposed to tell a lie while adults are supposed not to tell a lie*. *The sentence (B) implies that the person tells a lie like a child though he/she is an adult who is supposed not to tell a lie*.

---

### EDIT

> #### グループ１
>
> (A) 子供みたい**な**嘘をつく
> (B) 子供みたい**に**嘘をつく
>
> #### グループ２
>
> (C) 子供みたい**な**駄々をこねる
> (D) 子供みたい**に**駄々をこねる

グループ１では「な」と「に」とで意味が明確に異なることはすでに示した。
それでは、なぜ、ＯＰが言うようにグループ２では、「な」と「に」の違いで、意味が余り違わない、あるいは意味が違うように感じないのだろうか。
*In group 1, I already explained that the meanings clearly differ between (A) using "な" and (B) using "に"*. *Then, why does group 2 seem that the meaning is not so much different by the difference between "な" and "に" as OP says?*

それは、グループ１で明確であった「子供の嘘＝無邪気な嘘」対「大人の嘘＝陰険な嘘」あるいは「子供は嘘をつく」対「大人は嘘をつかない」という対立する概念の構図が、グループ２の「駄々」には描けないからである。
*That is because the composition of the opposing concept of "child's lie = innocent lie" vs. "adult's lie = insidious/crafty lie" or "childrens tell a lie" vs. "adults don't tell a lie" that was clear in group 1 can not be drawn about "駄々" in group 2.*

「子供みたいな駄々」、「大人みたいな駄々」という表現は存在しても、共通の認識として、各々がどのような「駄々」なのかとイメージすることは簡単でない。
*Even though there are expressions of "子供みたいな駄々" and "大人みたいな駄々", it is not easy to imagine what each "駄々" is, as a common perception.*

これは、「駄々」に対しては、「子供みたい」あるいは「非子供（＝大人）みたい」という修飾子が機能しないことを意味する。
*This means that modifiers such as "子供みたいな" or "non-子供みたいな (= 大人みたいな)" do not function to "駄々".*

従って、「子供みたいな」であっても「子供みたいに」であっても、「駄々」は「駄々」、「駄々をこねる」は「駄々をこねる」であって、意味をそれほど変えることはできない。
*Therefore, even if the modifier is "子供にみたいな" or "子供みたいに", "駄々" is "駄々" and "駄々をこねる" is "駄々をこねる" and they could not change the meaning so much.*

結論が遅くなりましたが、OPの直観は正しいと言えます。
*I'll tell OP the conclusion that your intuition is correct.*

---

### EDIT 2

グループ１は、「な」と「に」とで意味が変わるが、グループ２ではあまり意味が変わらないように見える理由を別の視点で見てみたい。
*In Group 1, the meaning changes with "な" and "ない", but in Group 2, it seems that the meaning does not change so much*. *I'll examine the reason  from another viewpoint apart from my original answer or from EDIT*.

> #### グループ１
>
> (A) 子供みたい**な**嘘をつく *The person tells a childish lie*.
> (B) 子供みたい**に**嘘をつく *The person tells like a child*.

(A)については、嘘には２種類ある。子供のつく無邪気な嘘。もう一つは大人のつく陰険な嘘。(A)の文章は、彼/彼女は大人なのに子供のような（無邪気な）嘘をつくという意味です。 従って、(A)は、文法的にも論理的にも間違いのない文と言える。

*As for (A), it implies that there are two kinds of lies. An innocent lie told by children. And an insidious/crafty lie told by adults*.
*(A) implies that the person tells an innocent lie just like being told by a child though he/she is an adult*. *So, this sentence is grammatically and also logically correct*.

(B)については、子供は嘘をつき、大人は嘘をつかないというように読める。これは、事実に反する。なぜなら、子供も大人も嘘をつく人と、つかない人とがいるからである。従って、(B)は、文法的には間違っていないが、論理的には間違っていることになる。

*As for (B), it implies that children lie and adults do not. This is contrary to the true fact, because some children and also adults would lie while others would not*. *So, this sentence is grammatically correct but logically incorrect*.

言い換えると、グループ１は、「な」「に」によって、論理的に意味を持つか持たないかで差が出るので、「な」「に」が機能しており、両方の文を読んだ人は、２つの文は違うと感じる。

*In other words, since Group 1 has a difference in logical correctness between the two sentences depending on whether they have "な" or "に", "な" or "に"  functions and those who read or hear both sentences feel that they are different*.

> #### グループ２
>
> (C) 子供みたい**な**駄々をこねる *The person throws a childish tantrum*.
> (D) 子供みたい**に**駄々をこねる *The person throws a tantrum like a child*.

(C)については、「駄々をこねる」は「子供みたいな」という修飾子がなくとも、最初から
子供が切れる状態を意味しているので、この修飾子が冗長である。

*Regarding (C), the modifier of "子供みたいな **childish**" is redundant, because "to throw a tantrum" means "to display a fit of **childish** anger" even without the modifier*.

従って、(C)を読んだ人は、この文が「大人なのに駄々をこねる」あるいは「大人なのに**子供のように**駄々をこねる」を意味していると読むことになる。これは、(C)が、(D)と全く同じであることを意味している。すなわち、グループ２の２つの文は、(C)の「な」を含む「子供みたいな」が機能しないことで同じ意味になる。

*Therefore, those who read or hear (C) would take the meaning of the sentence for that "大人なのに駄々をこねる the person throws a tantrum though he/she is an adult" or "大人なのに**子供のように**駄々をこねる the person throws a tantrum like a child though he/she is an adult."* *This means that (C) is exactly the same as (D)*. *That is, the two sentences of Group 2 have the same meaning because "子供みたいな" including "な" in (C) does not function*.

Comment: `これは、「駄々」に対しては、「子供みたい」あるいは「非子供（＝大人）みたい」という修飾子が機能しないことを意味する。` Maybe this should be clarified a bit? To me it reads like that 子供みたいな can't be used with 駄々 but you've explained what you mean earlier so I understand it, though. Anyway, explaining how 嘘をつく works compared to 駄々をこねる was really helpful so I'm accepting this answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think your intuition is correct. 子供みたいな駄々をこねる and 子供みたいに駄々をこねる sound almost the same to me, and I can hardly think of a situation where only either of the two is appropriate. Personally I would prefer 子供みたいに駄々をこねる because I also tend to treat 駄々をこねる as one big verbal phrase, but 子供みたいな駄々をこねる is not unnatural at all.

If you say 子供みたいな嘘, the focus is clearly on the content of the 嘘. On the other hand, 駄々 on its own means something like *quibbles* or *trivial claims*, and the content of 駄々 is unimportant by definition. Even if I heard 子供みたいな駄々, I would not feel what is said is important or focused.

Comment: `the content of 駄々 is unimportant by definition` thanks, this was really helpful.